# referencing typed element of tuple

Tags: tuples, eiffel

Discovering late (used to define classes instead) TUPLES and looking through the [documentation](https://archive.eiffel.com/doc/manuals/language/tuples/page.html) I was wondering if there is a mechanism to get the right type of a given `TUPLE`.
The goal is both anchoring its types and avoid having to test its type before getting an item.
Is there a language mechanism?

I also found few documentation about them, maybe I'm not looking at the right place.

For the following code I'd like to tell `like tuple_items.types[1]` and `tuple_items.typed_item (1)`

```eiffel
use_it
    do
        if attached {STRING} tuple_items.item (1) as l_tuple_item_1 then
            io.put_string (l_tuple_item_1)
        end
        if attached {DATE} tuple_items.item (1) as l_tuple_item_2 then
            io.put_string (l_tuple_item_2.out)
        end
        - ...
    end

tuple_items: TUPLE[STRING, DATE, INTEGER]
    local
        l_first: STRING -- like tuple_items.first?
    do
        Result := [l_first, create {DATE}.make_now, 1]
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A named tuple enables accessing the tuple items by name:

```
tuple_items: TUPLE [name: STRING; date: DATE; quantity: INTEGER]
```

Then, the feature `use_it` simplifies to

```
        io.put_string (tuple_items.name)
        io.put_string (tuple_items.date.out)
```

At the moment, tuple item names cannot be used in an anchored type, so there is no way to specify the type of `l_first` relative to the type of the tuple item. A workaround might be adding an anchor

```
name_anchor: STRING
    require 
        is_callable: False
    do
        check from_precondition: False then end
    end
```

and using it in anchored types, including the tuple declaration:

```
tuple_items: TUPLE [name: like name_anchor; date: DATE; quantity: INTEGER]
    local
        l_first: like name_anchor
```

Comment: Many thx! any documentation link about that might be useful on your answer

Comment: @Pipo Named tuples are mentioned in [ECMA-367 standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-367/).

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the anchor another way:

`name_anchor: detachable STRING`

Then the named-TUPLE reference changes slightly to:

`tuple_items: TUPLE [name: attached like name_anchor]`

If you want to ensure that `name_anchor` never becomes attached, you can add a class invariant:

`invariant type_anchor_only: not attached name_anchor`

This will prevent anything from trying to attach an object to your anchor. The downside is that this prevention code in the `invariant` is perhaps far removed from the location of the `name_anchor` feature in your code, which means another programmer may not easily pick up on the reason for the `invariant`. Hopefully, the tag on the contract helps to tell that story.

Comment: @Pipo—by the way—I tend to always label my "type anchors" with a suffix such as `?_anchor`. As a naming convention, it provides a clue as to the expectations of using the feature only as a type anchor and never as a feature for storing data or in computations.